# System.IO exception coming while saving XML document in C#

Tags: c#, xml

After importing plenty of XML files into application i tried to do modifications on it by using XML document class, for this i created few methods to do modifications.

The thing is the starting method it's working fine and when comes to the second one it's displaying System.IO exception like "File is already using another process".

So any one help me out how can i solve this issue.

Sample code what i'm doing:

```
Method1(fileList);
Method2(fileList);
Method3(fileList);

    private void Method1(IList<RenamedImportedFileInfo> fileList)
    {
           try
        {

            string isDefaultAttribute = Resource.Resources.ImportIsDefaultAttribute;
            string editorsPath = editorsFolderName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + meterType;
            string profilesPath = profileFolderName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + meterType;
            string strUriAttribute = Resource.Resources.ImportUriAttribute;

            foreach (RenamedImportedFileInfo renameInfo in fileList)
            {
                if (renameInfo.NewFilePath.ToString().Contains(editorsPath) && (renameInfo.IsProfileRenamed != true))
                {
                    var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmldoc.Load(renameInfo.NewFilePath);

                    if (xmldoc.DocumentElement.HasAttribute(isDefaultAttribute))
                    {
                        xmldoc.DocumentElement.Attributes[isDefaultAttribute].Value = Resource.Resources.ImportFalse;
                    }

                    XmlNodeList profileNodes = xmldoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName(Resource.Resources.ImportMeasurementProfileElement);
                    if (profileNodes.Count == 0)
                    {
                        profileNodes = xmldoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName(Resource.Resources.ImportBsMeasurementProfileElement);
                    }
                    if (profileNodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (RenamedImportedFileInfo profileName in oRenamedImportedFileList)
                        {
                            if (profileName.NewFilePath.ToString().Contains(profilesPath))
                            {
                                if (string.Compare(Path.GetFileName(profileName.OldFilePath), Convert.ToString(profileNodes[0].Attributes[strUriAttribute].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                                {
                                    profileNodes[0].Attributes[strUriAttribute].Value = Path.GetFileName(profileName.NewFilePath);
                                    renameInfo.IsProfileRenamed = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    xmldoc.Save(renameInfo.NewFilePath);
                    xmldoc = null;
                    profileNodes = null;
                }
            }
            oRenamedImportedFileList = null;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nullException) { LastErrorMessage = nullException.Message; }
    }
```

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: It will help if you demonstrate how you are managing the XML files.

Comment: Without any piece of code it's hard to tell, but I bet you're not disposing the file after first edit, so it's not getting closed until the GC sweeps in...

Comment: You're going to have to post your code. Clearly you're just missing a command or two, but how in the world are we to know without the code you currently have?

Comment: and please show the code of the methods, not how you call them.

Comment: Above i posted is the sample code same way i'm doinig modifications in remaining methods also

Comment: which line and what file causes the error?

Comment: When i tried to load same files from fileList in the immediate second method i'm getting this error.

Comment: It's showing different files in different times as 'File already using another process' not same file all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably opening the same file twice in your application. Before you can open it again, you have to close it (or leave it open and work on the same document without opening it again).

For help on how to implement this, please show us more code so we can give you advice.